# How to use grep output as a path for cd?

Tags: command-line, bash, directory, grep

How can I pipe `grep` output as an argument to the `cd` command?

For example:

```
[root@xxx xxx]# pip install django | grep '/usr.*'  
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django in   /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages
```

Here `/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages` is highlighted and I want to pass this string to `cd`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use Bash's [command substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution) `$()`, you also need `-o` with grep to only select the matched portion:

```
cd "$(pip install django | grep -o '/usr.*')"
```

Note that although you will get away in this case but you should always enclose the command substitution with double quotes so that the shell does not perform [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html) on whitespaces (by default space, tab and newline, depends on the `IFS` variable in case of `bash`).

Answer (score 9):

Depending on what you do and don't know beforehand about what `pip` will output, you might decide to `grep` for something other than `/usr.*`.

If you know **the directory starts with `/usr`** (and that it appears at the end of the line of output from `pip`, and that `/usr` does not appear anywhere on the line before the directory name), then that's a fine choice; [heemayl's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/613043/22949) tells you how.

<sup>If the *reason* you know it starts with `/usr` is that you have just run the command and know the directory you want to change to, I suggest the simpler solution of running the command `cd /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages`. This is less typing even if you don't make use of [tab completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_completion).</sup>

Otherwise, you might choose a different regexp depending on what you know about the output being parsed. All the alternatives below still assume the directory name appears at the end of the line, but the other assumptions vary.

If you know **the directory name is absolute** (i.e., starts with a `/`) **and no `/` appears on the line before the directory name**, you can use the same regexp as in [heemayl's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/613043/22949) but with `/` instead of `/usr`:

```
cd "$(pip install django | grep -o '/.*')"
```

This matches a `/` followed by zero or more (`*`) of any character (`.`).

If you know **the directory name contains no horizontal whitespace** (no spaces or tabs) and **appears at the end of the line**, you can use:

```
cd "$(pip install django | grep -oP '[^\h]+$')"
```

Here I've used [a Perl regexp](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/perlre.1.html) (`-P`) because the `\h` abbreviation (for `[:blank:]`) makes this easier to type and to read than an equivalent extended regexp (`-E`). This matches one or more (`+`) of any character in a class of characters (`[` `]`) that is *not* (`^`) a space or tab (`\h`).

If you know t**he directory name is immediately preceded by `in` surrounded by horizontal whitespace** (i.e., padded on both the left and the right with blanks), and that **this is the only such occurrence of `in` on the line**, you can use:

```
cd "$(pip install django | grep -oP '\hin\h+\K.+')"
```

This uses a zero-width positive look-behind assertion (`\K`) to match one or more characters (`.+`) that appear after a space or tab (`\h`), `in`, and another one or more spaces or tabs (`\h+`), without actually including `in` and the blank spaces surrounding it in the match. [Look-around assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) are a feature of Perl regular expressions.

The pattern `\h+in\h+\K.+` would have worked also, but we only need to look for one blank before `in`, regardless of how many are present. In contrast, we must match *all* the blanks after `in`, or they wouldn't be discarded by `\K` and they would be matched as part of the directory name.

If you know **the directory name is immediately preceded by the line's *last* occurrence of `in` followed by horizontal whitespace**, you can use:

```
set +H
cd "$(pip install django | grep -oP '\hin\h+(?!.*\hin\h.*)\K.*')"
set -H
```

There, the zero-width positive look-behind assertion itself contains a zero-width negative look-ahead assertion (`(?!` `)`).

The `!` appears in such a way as to be difficult [to escape](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting) elegantly; the method I have used to prevent it from triggering shell [history expansion](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#History-Interaction) before being passed to `grep` is to temporarily disable history expansion (`set +H`) before running the command and re-enable it (`set -H`) afterwards. If you're using this in a script and your script doesn't contain `set -H`, you don't need to do this as history expansion is enabled automatically only when a shell runs interactively.

*Finally, note that none of these, nor [heemayl's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/613043/22949), are actually piping the output of `grep` to `cd` (though the output of `pip` is still being piped to `grep`). Rather than [pipes](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines), the appropriate tool for this job is [command substitution](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution).*

Comment: Of course, if you want to get _technical_, the shell uses a pipe internally to read the command output.

Comment: @Random832 Good point--I've edited slightly in consideration of this. Btw, do you know if the use of pipes "under the hood" in command substitution can be relied on? Or is it an implementation detail that might potentially be done differently in a different, future version of bash? (Of course, in practice, I understand it's the *best* way to do it, and thus it's unlikely to be implemented differently.)

Comment: No, it's not guaranteed, in theory a shell could use a named fifo or temp file, though there's no reason to.

Comment: Are you sure about the history expansion? The only characters that can block it are `\` and `'`, and you have use single quotes around the grep expression.

Comment: @muru [Yes, it's expanded.](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10919534/) I hadn't noticed either, but found out when I tested it. The `!` there isn't quoted with `'`-quotes, as the `'`-quotes are themselves quoted. The command's complexity makes it easy to mis-predict its effect, but [apparently due to the order of expansions (`!` is early)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22130745) it ends up working like `x=foo; echo "'$x'"` (--> `'foo'`). Removing the outer `"`-quotes would cause `!` to be `'`-quoted and prevent history expansion, but then `cd`  would fail if the directory has whitespace in its name.